# Problem: torch.distributed.barrier() stuck. How to solve it?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to use `DistributedDataParallel` and have written code for the same. However, I am encountering an issue where the processes halt when I use `torch.distributed.barrier()` after `init_process_group()`.

Below is the code snippet in question:

```py
dist.init_process_group(backend="nccl",
                        world_size=opts.world_size,
                        rank=opts.local_rank)
```

Interestingly, when I change the backend from `"nccl"` to `"gloo"`, the code works seamlessly, but I prefer to use the `"nccl"` mode.

Here are the versions I'm working with:

```
Python: 3.8.14
PyTorch: 2.2.0
CUDA: 12.1
```

I have also inspected the NCCL logs (using export `NCCL_DEBUG=INFO`), but couldn't identify any issues..